# How to detect device orientation changed while activity is locked to portrait mode?

Tags: android

### Goal

In my application, I need to detect when the screen orientation become `ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT` while activity is locked to `portrait` mode. Is there a way to do this?

### Scenario

More specifically, think of this scenario. I am watching a video on landscape layout. When I press the "exit fullscreen" button, the `activity.requestedOrientation` is set to `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT`, and the display rotates but the phone is still sideways. I don't want the display to rotate back to landscape until the user physically rotates their phone to portrait first. Exactly how youtube app works. To achieve this, I need to set `activity.requestedOrientation` to `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED` when the user rotates their device to portrait. I don't know how to be notified of this event.

### Attempts made

I tried to use `OrientationEventListener.onOrientationChanged()`. However, this is called whenever the angle of the device is changed. Not very useful.

Comment: I think your goal is orientation become orientation_portrait while activity is locked to landscape mode? The other way around make no sense.

Comment: @DEX7RA if you could help me do that, that would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it programmatically use:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
//Do your operation
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
```

Comment: As I stated in the question, I change the screenOrientation programmatically using `activity.requestedOrientation`. This doesn't answer my question.

Comment: I updated my answer. Sorry didn't understood that right. Hope that helps :)